# How to delete a array value into a resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next service:

```
function Lawyer($resource, BaseUrl) {
  return $resource(BaseUrl + '/lawyers/:lawyerId',{lawyerId: '@_id'});
}
```

Then, in my controller, I have the next code for delete a "lawyer":

```
function LawyerDeleteController($routeParams, Lawyer){
  Lawyer.delete({id: $routeParams.lawyerId});
}
```

But it does not work because the return value is a resource and not a array. The array is within that resource:

> Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false} $promise:Promise
>   $resolved:true lawyers:Array[18]
>   **proto**:Object

How to delete a array value into a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deleting items, it is better to use $http.delete Instead of $resource.

```
        $http.delete(url, config).then(
        function (response) {
            // success callback
        },
        function (response) {
            // failure call back
        }
    );
```